# What causes Django to use 500.html only 3 out of 6 times?

Tags: python, django

This is the bizarre.

I have a 500.html template below. When I refer to a page that does not exist via the url, my 500.html will show three times (if I try to reload the page repeatedly), then I get the apache Internal Server Error three times. My broser keeps flipping between the two.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Page unavailable</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Page unavailable</h1>
    <p>Sorry, but the requested page is unavailable due to a
    server hiccup.</p>
    <p>Our engineers have been notified, so check back later.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

During the three times I get the Apache Internal Server Error, the error logs say 500.html does not exist - but it does. It pulled it up three times before.

I cleared the cache and tried a different browser with the same results.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT 1

Excerpt from error log:

```
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_python (pid=8262, interpreter='127.0.1.1', phase='PythonHandler', handler='django.core.handlers.modpython'): Application error
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ServerName: '127.0.1.1'
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] DocumentRoot: '/var/www'
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] URI: '/test'
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Location: '/test'
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory: None
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Filename: '/www/test/wsgi.py'
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PathInfo: ''
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch\n    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target\n    result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target\n    result = object(arg)
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 180, in handler\n    return ModPythonHandler()(req)
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 158, in __call__\n    response = self.get_response(request)
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 153, in get_response\n    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception\n    return callback(request, **param_dict)
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view\n    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 32, in server_error\n    t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 145, in get_template\n    template, origin = find_template(template_name)
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template\n    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
[Tue Mar 05 22:28:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

Comment: Can you show the excerpt of the error logs?

Comment: Are you sure it says that `500.html` does not exist?  If you're hitting a page that doesn't match a URL, you should be getting a `404` error.  If you haven't defined a `404.html` template, that will generate a `500` with a message along the lines of "404 template could not be found".

Comment: It matches a url, but there is no template for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try restarting apache. I've noticed inconsistencies in how urls are handled after any change. This sounds very similar to a problem I had when a url would sometimes load on refresh.

Comment: I thought I had restarted it. I guess not. This fixed it. Thanks.